# Vacuum Equalization

Tags: pressure, vacuum, gas

If I have two evacuated chambers each 10m on a side. Both are strong Vacuums but one is a slightly lower pressure than the other (A is the lowest pressure vacuum [ 10x-10 tor], B is the slightly higher pressure vacuum [10x-8 tor]).

When I open a connection between the two chambers, how quickly will they equalize?

It's my assumption that with very low pressures it will take a while--but if the gas particles are moving at like the speed of sound, maybe it will be very fast?

Comment: Entirely dependent on the geometry and length of the connection between them.   You should probably also define how close is "equal" as the pressure difference will decay asymptotically to zero